# Selenium not giving whats inside a class?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

```
PATH = "D:\CDriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://www.se.com/ww/en/about-us/careers/job-details/inside-sales-associate/006ZMV')
TITLE = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sdl-application-job-details__job-title')
print(TITLE)
driver.quit()
```

I have all the needed imports, I just wanted to leave them out.

When I run this the output SHOULD be: **Inside Sales Associate**

But instead it gives me this: `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement,` the session and element code.

What do I need to do to make it print what it should print. I have tried `by_tag_name('h1.sdl-application-job-details__job-title')` but that gives the exact same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The find_element methods return web elements. Just pass `print(TITLE.text)`

Answer (score 1):

There is a inbuilt `title` method available in **Selenium**. You can call that method on `driver object` **not on** `web element`.

**Code :**

```
driver.get('https://www.se.com/ww/en/about-us/careers/job-details/inside-sales-associate/006ZMV')
driver.title
print(driver.title)
```

or if you want to retrieve text inside any web element, you could probably do something like this :

```
class_value = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1[class$='sdl-application-job-details__job-title']").text
print(class_value)
```